# AngularJS UI datePicker always one day off

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

Im using AngularJS UI datePicker on a app, there are three date inputs on a form. No matter what date is selected and saved, the day is always one day ahead. I have tried every combination on date format and searched every forum post on this subject, but nothing works. What can I change on my code to get the correct day when a date is selected?

JS

```
configAppControllers.controller('deadLineDatePickerCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.today = function () {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function (date, mode) {
        // return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
    };

    $scope.toggleMin = function () {
        $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.open = function ($event, id) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
        $timeout(function () {
            $("#" + id).focus();
        });
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.initDate = new Date('2012/03/21');
    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[3];
  }
]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-group deadline">
  <input name="deadLine" id="deadLine" type="text" class="form-control" 
    data-ng-required="true"
    datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
    data-ng-model="programDetails.deadline" 
    is-open="opened" 
    min-date="programDetails.startDate"
    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
    date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
    close-text="Close"
    show-button-bar="false"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="open($event)"><i
            class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
   </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has this same problem with dates being a day off with datePicker plugin, I was able to solve this by using the getTimezoneOffset() method like this:

```
user.deadline = formatDate(new Date(deadlineDate.getTime() + deadlineDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
```

Solved the problem!!